# Парсинг Razor страниц в отдельном AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, appdomain

я пытаюсь написать библиотеку которая будет заниматься отправкой сообщение на email. Мне необходимо сделать парсинг Razor страниц, я наше библиотеки которые это делают (RazorEngine и RazorLight). Как многие возможно знают в asp.net MVC razor страниц предварительно компилируется в отдельную dll и сохраняются на диски, а т.к у меня все это делаетсяв runtime она у меня сохраняется в контексте app domain и это невозможно выгрузить из него(только перезагрузив AppDOmain).  RazorEngine  поддерживает Izolated Razor т.е парсинг в отдельном домене. Но это работает исключительно на net fraemwork, тогда как моя либа на писана на .net core(https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine.Core.NetCore/ есть реализация RazorEngine  для net core без Izolated Razor). Других либ я не нашел которые поддерживали бы эту функцию. Может кто-то может мне посоветовать, что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Гм, что-то я не пойму. Это же ваше приложение? Тогда зачем парсить выхлоп razor, если вы можете просто взять данные в нужном месте и послать email.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Есть набор интерфейсов которые определяют поведение, дабы можно было легко подменять реализацию. Отдельные функциональности разбиты по разным либам дабы не грузить лишнее. Razor Parser лишь просто одна из либ которая реализует интерфейс и которую можно подменить на другую.